# Vertical scrollbar in code snippet overlap userbar

Tags: bug, code, scrollbar

When scrolling the code snippet up and down, the vertical scrollbar is overlapping the top user bar which, I think in an ideal case, should be below.

Not sure if this should be called a bug but I feel it should not behave like this.

Google Chrome : Version 64.0.3282
macOS Sierra : 10.12.6

Example gif:
[image: example gif of this happening]

Example screen recording:
http://recordit.co/xu7P2OoBzP

Comment: All okay here in Chrome 64.0.3282.167 win64 and FF 58.0.1 win64. How do you scroll?

Comment: I can replicate this issue using the same browser and OS, but only when macOS Sierra's *General -> Show scroll bars* option is set to "When scrolling". Setting it to "Automatic based on mouse or trackpad" or "Always" does not cause this problem to occur.

Comment: This issue can be resolved by applying CSS to the `pre` tag to include `position: relative` and `z-index: 1`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev apple magic mouse :)

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: @Makyen I no longer use macOS